# How to add comments under each posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that functions like a blog. I want to add comments beneath each post (i.e on the posts page have a comment box under all posts listed) in this format

Post title
Post Content
Leave a reply box

Post title
Post Content
Leave a reply box

Post title
Post Content
Leave a reply box

Just like you have on facebook you can comment on each post without taking you to another page

Comment: you can enable "discussion" in posts

Comment: how do i do that @charankumar, please is it a plugin

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on function.php file,

```html
function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'podcast',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Podcast' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Podcast' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Episode' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Episode' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/podcast-icon.png', // 16px16
            'menu_position' => 9,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'post-templates'),
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_podcast_metaboxes' // This registers the metabox that we'll add later.
        )
    );
}
```

**Second Step Like,**

Comments are disabled by default for custom-post-types. This happens even if you have them enabled in the overall settings

To fix it, all I had to do was the following:

1. In SETTINGS > DISCUSSION uncheck the "Allow people to post comments on new articles" setting.
2. Click "Save Changes"
3. Now go back and re-check "Allow people to post comments on new articles"
4. Click "Save Changes"

It seems that for custom post types you need to kind of kick-start this setting. All new posts for created custom-post-types will have the box enabled by default. Existing posts will retain their previous setting. I'm assuming it's the same for allowing trackbacks. Hopefully this helps !!

Comment: i have added this to function.php file. The comment box is not coming up beneath each post. Do i have to do any other thing apart from just adding it to the function.php file

Comment: I have done as you have said. it is still not working. Here is the dummy wordpress site i am trying to implement it on. https://naspire1.000webhostapp.com

Comment: I don't get any error. I want the comment box to show under every post, its not working. Should i give you the details to log in it's just a dummy site